# Access denied to MySQL, cannot create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql-connector, apache-commons-dbcp, mysql-8.0

While configuring an open source project ran into a problem trying to connect the application to the MySQL database running locally. After figuring out some incompatibilities due to some changes introduced by MySQL 8.0, a connection cannot be created even though the details are correct and the user has all privileges, having tried with both root and another manually created users with privileges manually assigned. The My SQL Manager class is as follows.

```
public class MySqlManager {
    private static PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource;

    private static int minIdle;
    private static int maxIdle;

    public static void initialize()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IllegalArgumentException {
        minIdle = Configuration.getInt("mysql.idle.min");
        maxIdle = Configuration.getInt("mysql.idle.max");

        if (minIdle < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(Localization.get("mysql.error.pool"));
        }

        System.out.println("Host: " + Configuration.get("mysql.host"));
        System.out.println("Port: " + Configuration.get("mysql.port"));
        System.out.println("User: " + Configuration.get("mysql.user"));
        System.out.println("Pass: " + Configuration.get("mysql.pass"));

        // Load JDBC Driver. ClassNotFoundException may be thrown.
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        // jdbc:mysql://host:port/database/?args
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" +
                Configuration.get("mysql.host") + ":" +
                Configuration.get("mysql.port") + "/" +
                Configuration.get("mysql.database") + "?" +
                "zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL" + "&" +
                "autoReconnect=true";

        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        setupDataSource(url, Configuration.get("mysql.user"), Configuration.get("mysql.pass"));

        // Check if the connection with the database is working, otherwise SQLException is thrown
        try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
            if (con == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Retrieved dataSource connection is null.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setupDataSource(String url, String user, String password) {
        PoolableConnectionFactory factory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(
                new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(url, user, password), null);

        GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxTotal(maxIdle);
        config.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        config.setMinIdle(minIdle);

        ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(factory, config);

        factory.setPool(connectionPool);

        dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    }

    static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    private MySqlManager() {}
}
```

Error message shows `Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.`

Framework versions include MySQL 8.0.16, DBCP 2.6.0, MySQL-Connector-Java 8.0.16. Proof of privileges for the said user is as follows.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `joao`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `joao`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: `Configuration.get("mysql.database") + "&" +` - did you mean `Configuration.get("mysql.database") + "?" +`?

Comment: @BackSlash yes, that was an error. however, a different problem happens. the question was edited. – Joao Pereira 5 mins ago

Comment: Is your mysql server on the local box?

Comment: @PeterHe not sure if I follow the question. are you asking if the MySQL server is running locally? if so, yes. Xampp is running MySQL on port 3308.

Comment: Yes, that was my asking. Can you use other mysql client tools like mysql cli to login to the mysql server with the account joao? Just to narrow down it is the account/mysql setting issue or your app's issue first.

Comment: @PeterHe I can access the database through the cli and phpmyadmin with said user just fine. has to be an app issue. note that this project hasn't been maintained for three years, so some compatibility issues are to be expected. the problem is that this error is completely non descriptive and I couldn't infer the cause from the stacktrace either.

Comment: you can try to add &useSSL=false to the connection url. Also for the new cj driver, need to specify the serverTimezone

Comment: @PeterHe Tried `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3308/kicksdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT` without success. Also found some information online that MySQL might interpret localhost and 127.0.0.1 differently but already tried to create another user with `@127.0.0.1` with no success either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195934/discussion-between-joao-pereira-and-peterhe).